# ctor error function already defined and has different type c++ or mql

Tags: c++, mql5, mql

i define class with ctor and use it in my code but compiler give me error

```
class MovingAvrage_Expert
{
public:
   MovingAvrage_Expert(void);
   ~MovingAvrage_Expert(void);
   bool Init(void);
   double TradeSizeOptimized(void);
   void CheckForOpen(void);
   void CheckForClose(void);
   bool SelectPosition();
}

MovingAvrage_Expert::MovingAvrage_Expert(void)
{
}

MovingAvrage_Expert::~MovingAvrage_Expert(void)
{
}

... more function

MovingAvrage_Expert maExpert;

// MQL Function

int OnInit(void)
{
   if (!maExpert.Init())
   {
      printf("Error creating indicator");
      return (INIT_FAILED);
   }
   return (INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

void OnTick(void)
{
   if (maExpert.SelectPosition())
      maExpert.CheckForClose();
   else
      maExpert.CheckForOpen();
}
```

my error

> 'MovingAvrage_Expert' - function already defined and has different
> type  Expert Advisors.mq5 48  22

where is my problem ?

Comment: Don't use void for default constructors and destructors.

Comment: `void` shouldn't be used at all in C++ function arguments, you generally only need to use it in C functions with no arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just should write ; after class

```
class MovingAvrage_Expert
{
public:
   MovingAvrage_Expert(void);
   ~MovingAvrage_Expert(void);
   bool Init(void);
   double TradeSizeOptimized(void);
   void CheckForOpen(void);
   void CheckForClose(void);
   bool SelectPosition();
};
```

:)